# Convert bytes embedded in list (or dict) to str for use with json.dumps

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that receives a Python list or dict that may have nested bytes that need to be converted to str before calling json.dumps.

The data structure received by the function is not well-known. It could be a list, could be nested structures, and could have multiple data types. If it was just being passed a byte encoded string a simple decode() would do the trick.

```
>>> foo = [b'dog', b'cat', b'cow']
>>> foo2 = [f.decode() for f in foo]
>>> foo2
['dog', 'cat', 'cow']`
>>> json.dumps(foo2)
'["dog", "cat", "cow"]'
```

but in this case we are receiving more complex structures (I truncated traceback for brevity).

```
>>> foo = [[14, 3.5, b'Tom'], [18, -1.2, b'Larry'], [22, -1.7, b'Sue']]
>>> json.dumps(foo)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

Would like to have a function that can take an arbitrary Python struct (list, dict, etc) and return the same with all bytes decoded.

```
>>> foo = [[14, 3.5, b'Tom'], [18, -1.2, b'Larry'], [22, -1.7, b'Sue']]
>>> foo2 = mydecoder(foo)
>>> foo2
[[14, 3.5, 'Tom'], [18, -1.2, 'Larry'], [22, -1.7, 'Sue']]
>>> json.dumps(foo2)
'[[14, 3.5, "Tom"], [18, -1.2, "Larry"], [22, -1.7, "Sue"]]'
```

So question is how do you implement a mydecoder function that can take arbitrary lists/dicts, possibly nested, with different types and return the same struct with all bytes decoded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a subclass of [`json.JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) to `json.dumps` that can handle special cases of stringifying your bytes. This will let you avoid dealing with nested structures and edges cases which the json encoder already does really well. You just tell it what to do when it sees `bytes`

Here, you can just handle `bytes` and let the default encoder do the rest:

```
import json

class BytesDump(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, bytes):                   # deal with bytes
            return obj.decode() 
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)   # everything else

foo = [{"key": b'value'}, [14, 3.5, b'Tom'], [18, -1.2, b'Larry'], [22, -1.7, 'Sue']]

json.dumps(foo, cls=BytesDump)
```

**result**:

```
'[{"key": "value"}, [14, 3.5, "Tom"], [18, -1.2, "Larry"], [22, -1.7, "Sue"]]'
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This works great for my lists but still having issue with any `dict` where key is byte encoded. For example
`foo = {b'key': value}` or `foo = ['first', 'second', { b'name': 'bob', b'age': 18 }]`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry was a bit to fast first time. Here is how to convert and back:

```
import json

foo = [[14, 3.5, b'Tom'], [18, -1.2, b'Larry'], [22, -1.7, b'Sue']]
print(foo)
# to save
foo = [[i, j, k.decode("utf-8") ] for i, j, k in foo]
json_str = json.dumps(foo)

# to reload
foo = json.loads(json_str)
foo = [[i, j, bytes(k, 'utf-8')] for i, j, k in foo]

print(foo)
```